# I am having trouble using tolower() in C++

Tags: c++, string, tolower

When I try to use tolower on a string, rather than making the letters lowercase, the program converts them to random symbols.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string hi= "thTSMSdjNnJlJjnJJKn";
    for (int i=0; i<hi.length(); i++)
    {
        hi[i]+=tolower(hi[i]);
        cout << hi[i];
    }
}
```

This is the output: Þð╚ã║ã╚È╝▄┤Ï┤È▄┤┤Â▄

What is wrong with it? This isn't the actual code that I want to use tolower on but I just put it in a separate example so it was more clear. I don't mind using to upper either but the main thing is that I get all the letters in the string to be the same case.

Comment: hi[i]+=tolower(hi[i]); -> hi[i]=tolower(hi[i]);

Comment: `hi[i]+= ??` Should be closed as a typo...

Comment: you don't `#include <string>` at first , second `hi[i]=tolower(hi[i]);` should work

Comment: ok thanks, If someone just puts that in an answer I can vote it best answer because thats all I needed.

Comment: For standard compliance it should be either `tolower(hi[i],locale())` or `tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(hi[i]))`.  Modern compilers all allow your usage though as it is such a common mistake.

Answer (score 3):

There's a typo in the for loop:

```
hi[i] += tolower(hi[i]);
```

should be

```
hi[i] = tolower(hi[i]);
```

Also, your code is missing `#include <string>`